# Убрать отступ после </html>

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Появляется отступ после html документа, который я никак не могу убрать и так же не могу понять за счет чего он появляется ?

```css
html,body,pre,h1,h2,h3,h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
pre{
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    background-color: #20495B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 18px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
} 
.first__display{
background-color: #20495B;
}

.phone > pre{
    font-family: Oswaldregular;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #D5EBF2;
}
.header__wrapper__menu{
    display: flex;
}
.menu{
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.container{
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}
.header__flex{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section{
    position: relative;
}
.position{
    position: relative;
    height: 370px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.first__display__mobile__text,
.first__display__web__text{
    font-family: Oswaldbold;
    font-size: 370px;
    color: #25586E;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 370px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/newstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__flex">
            <div class="col-10">
                <a href="/" class="header__logo">
                  <img src="" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                <a href="" class="phone">
                    <pre>+38090-123-4567-89</pre>
                  </a>
                  <a href="" class="menu"><img src="" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>  
  <main>
    <section class="first__display">
      <div class="container">
            <h2 class="first__display__mobile__text">LOREM</h2>
       <ul>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum voluptatem vero debitis quas corrupti, itaque illum. Laudantium voluptas numquam aut ex perspiciatis, quidem consequuntur, esse amet blanditiis magnam fuga quae.</li>
         <li>Eius animi quam similique, iusto voluptates rem aliquam at iure suscipit reprehenderit eligendi, vero laudantium consequuntur expedita iste, blanditiis explicabo non quidem possimus porro id autem officiis voluptate quo? Modi.</li>
         <li>Voluptate eius similique dicta ratione, iusto eligendi. Et, unde nulla quo sint tempora odit. Praesentium ex saepe, odio ratione et autem at. Ducimus aliquid, molestias minima laboriosam deserunt ratione inventore.</li>
         <li>Odio officia laboriosam fugiat voluptate error harum magnam possimus dolor vitae aliquid at, molestias, atque neque commodi modi iure nobis vel reiciendis ab ipsum repellendus sunt quaerat! Fugit, et voluptas?</li>
         <li>Dolore asperiores ea similique, corrupti odio placeat cum modi, consequatur est inventore veniam aliquam non, dolores nostrum accusantium deserunt quae nulla? Ipsa numquam, perferendis sunt placeat excepturi ullam aliquid iusto.</li>
         <li>Quas, praesentium quos voluptates id quasi animi minima laboriosam dolore dolores obcaecati, sit eum officiis? Corporis voluptatibus sint impedit ratione perspiciatis deleniti eos aliquid id magni unde veritatis, nihil distinctio?</li>
       </ul>
       
        <h2 class="first__display__web__text text-right">IPSUM</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Где появляется?

Comment: В самом низу , небольшой, белый, отступ

Comment: @ Andrew Kozhemyakin в этом классе .first__display__web__text уберите или уменьшите  line-height: 370px;

Comment: У `<container>` отступа нет — просто у него недостаточная высота. Можете добавить фон для `<body>`, если не критично.

Comment: @IgorR. Критично

Comment: @Leks пробовал , не помогает

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin в моем ответе белая линия убралась

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin попробуйте увелить line-height до 405px

Comment: @Andrew Kozhemyakin также попробуйте font-size уменьшить до 330px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html,body,pre,h1,h2,h3,h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
pre{
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    background-color: #20495B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 18px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
} 
.first__display{
background-color: #20495B;
}

.phone > pre{
    font-family: Oswaldregular;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #D5EBF2;
}
.header__wrapper__menu{
    display: flex;
}
.menu{
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.container{
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}
.header__flex{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section{
    position: relative;
}
.position{
    position: relative;
    height: 370px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.first__display__mobile__text,
.first__display__web__text{
    font-family: Oswaldbold;
    font-size: 370px;
    color: #25586E;
    position: relative;
    /*line-height: 370px;*/ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/newstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__flex">
            <div class="col-10">
                <a href="/" class="header__logo">
                  <img src="" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                <a href="" class="phone">
                    <pre>+38090-123-4567-89</pre>
                  </a>
                  <a href="" class="menu"><img src="" alt=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>  
  <main>
    <section class="first__display">
      <div class="container">
            <h2 class="first__display__mobile__text">LOREM</h2>
       <ul>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum voluptatem vero debitis quas corrupti, itaque illum. Laudantium voluptas numquam aut ex perspiciatis, quidem consequuntur, esse amet blanditiis magnam fuga quae.</li>
         <li>Eius animi quam similique, iusto voluptates rem aliquam at iure suscipit reprehenderit eligendi, vero laudantium consequuntur expedita iste, blanditiis explicabo non quidem possimus porro id autem officiis voluptate quo? Modi.</li>
         <li>Voluptate eius similique dicta ratione, iusto eligendi. Et, unde nulla quo sint tempora odit. Praesentium ex saepe, odio ratione et autem at. Ducimus aliquid, molestias minima laboriosam deserunt ratione inventore.</li>
         <li>Odio officia laboriosam fugiat voluptate error harum magnam possimus dolor vitae aliquid at, molestias, atque neque commodi modi iure nobis vel reiciendis ab ipsum repellendus sunt quaerat! Fugit, et voluptas?</li>
         <li>Dolore asperiores ea similique, corrupti odio placeat cum modi, consequatur est inventore veniam aliquam non, dolores nostrum accusantium deserunt quae nulla? Ipsa numquam, perferendis sunt placeat excepturi ullam aliquid iusto.</li>
         <li>Quas, praesentium quos voluptates id quasi animi minima laboriosam dolore dolores obcaecati, sit eum officiis? Corporis voluptatibus sint impedit ratione perspiciatis deleniti eos aliquid id magni unde veritatis, nihil distinctio?</li>
       </ul>
       
        <h2 class="first__display__web__text text-right">IPSUM</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  
</body>
</html>
```

1. В классе **.first__display__web__text** убираем или уменьшаем   /*line-height: 370px;*/